# click e hover não funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, estou a desenvolver um projecto, onde tenho um click em uma div que após clicada é colocada ou retirada uma class de um elemento dentro dela que faz aparecer e desaparecer uma cruz, mas por algum motivo assim que eu troquei os dados estáticos para testes por dados vindos da API esse click deixou de funcionar assim como um outro efeito hover que em principio deve vir do mesmo problema. Abaixo no código vão encontrar este comentário "Em baixo esta o problema do click que não é executado" é ai que esta o problema. Se eu colocar a função do click ainda dentro do ajax acima só a primeira div do botão funciona as restantes não.

```js
window.onload = function() {
          $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://2.81.244.98/dns/admin/api.php",
        data: {
            task: "clean"
        }
        });
      $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://2.81.244.98/dns/admin/api.php",
      data: { task: "validatecook", all: true }
    })
      .done(function( msg ) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(msg);
      });
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://2.81.244.98/dns/admin/api.php",
      data: { task: "listarSites"}
    })
      .done(function( msg ) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(msg);
        for (var i = 0; i < obj['ids'].length; i++) {
          if(obj['ativos'][i] === "0"){
            var backgroundC = 'class="disable"';
            var rasurado = 'rasurado';
          }else{
            var backgroundC = '';
            var rasurado = '';
          }
          $("#tabela").append('<tr ' + backgroundC + '><td class="espca"><div id="select" data-secid="' + obj['ids'][i] + '"><label class="cruz desativado">X</label></div></td><td class="espca ' + rasurado + '" width="10">' + obj['webpage'][i] + '</td><td class="espca ' + rasurado + '">' + obj['categorias'][i] + '</td><td class="espca"><button><label><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></label></button></td></tr>');
        }
      });
     $(".exit").click(function() {
    saida();
    });
      $("#select").hover(
      function() {
        $("#tabela").addClass("noselect");
      }, function() {
        $("#tabela").removeClass("noselect");
      }
    );
     // Em baixo esta o problema do click que não é executado
      $("#select").click(function() {
        $(this).find('.cruz').toggleClass('desativado');
      });
    $(".new").click(function() {
      location.href = "new.html";
    });
    $(".list").click(function() {
      location.href = "painel.html";
    });
    $(".cats").click(function() {
      location.href = "cats.html";
    });
    $(".req").click(function() {
      location.href = "requests.html";
    });

    if(getParameter("opt") != false){
      var opt = getParameter("opt");
    if(opt == "exit"){
          $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://2.81.244.98/dns/admin/api.php",
      data: { task: "logout"}
    })
      .done(function( msg ) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(msg);
        if(obj['res'] == "ok"){
          location.href = "index.html";
        }
      });
      }
    }
    }
     function getParameter(theParameter) {
      var params = window.location.search.substr(1).split('&');
      for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
          var p = params[i].split('=');
          if (p[0] == theParameter) {
              return decodeURIComponent(p[1]);
          }
      }
      return false;
    }
    function saida(){
      var cnf = confirm("Pretendes realmente sair?");
      if (cnf == true) {
        location.href = 'painel.html?opt=exit';
      }
    }
```

```css
* {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing:border-box;
        }
        body {
          font-family: Helvetica;
          -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        }
        ul {
          list-style-type: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
          background-color: #333;
        }
        li {
          float: left;
        }
        li a {
          display: block;
          color: white;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 14px 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
        li a:hover:not(.active) {
          background-color: #111;
        }
        .wellcome{
            background-color: #444;
        }
        .wc{
    padding: 14px 16px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
  }
  .modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 18%;
}
div#regit{
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
div#regit #tabela{
  table-layout:fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.espca{
   word-wrap:break-word;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}
.espca button{
  padding: 10px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
.espca button label{
  cursor: pointer;
}
div#regit #tabela tr:hover:not(.header){
  background: #f3f3f3;
}
div#select{
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 40px;
  background: #FFF;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}
.cruz{
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.desativado{
  visibility: hidden;
}
.noselect{
  user-select: none;
}
div#btns button{
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #00b4fa;
  outline: none;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
div#btns button:hover{
  background: #09F;
}
div#btns button:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 8px;
}
.disable{
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
.rasurado{
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>SMART DNS | Controlo de Bloqueios</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" media="all">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wellcome">
<p class="wc"></p>
</div>
<ul>
<li><a class="new" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="far fa-plus-square"></i> Novo Registo</a></li>
<li><a class="list active" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fas fa-list"></i> Lista de Sites</a></li>
<li><a class="cats" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fas fa-quote-right"></i> Lista de Categorias</a></li>
<li><a class="req" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fas fa-network-wired"></i> Pedidos de Desbloqueios</a></li>
<li style="float:right"><a class="exit" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Sair</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="regit">
<div id="btns">
<button>Selecionar Todos</button>
<button>Remover Selecções</button>
<button>Ativar Itens Selecionados</button>
<button>Desativar Itens Selecionados</button>
<button>Apagar Itens Selecionados</button>
</div>
<table id="tabela">
<tr class="header">
<td class="espca">Selecionar</td>
<td class="espca">Pagina Web</td>
<td class="espca">Categorias</td>
<td class="espca">Editar</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: acrescente tbm seu html para que possamos simular o que vc está fazendo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, um id deve ser um seletor único, você está adicionando vários elementos com o mesmo Id na tela... Troque o seletor de id pra classe ou algum seletor de sua preferência.

Segundo, ao adicionar o elemento com JQuery, a função .click() já vai estar carregada, logo o elemento não será reconhecido, adicione a função [.on("click", handle)](https://api.jquery.com/on/) para adicionar o evento à elementos adicionados dinamicamente à DOM.

```
//Removido o Id e adicionado o class="select" à div que necessita o evento
$("#tabela").append('<tr ' + backgroundC + '><td class="espca"><div class="select" data-secid="' + obj['ids'][i] + '"><label class="cruz desativado">X</label></div></td><td class="espca ' + rasurado + '" width="10">' + obj['webpage'][i] + '</td><td class="espca ' + rasurado + '">' + obj['categorias'][i] + '</td><td class="espca"><button><label><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></label></button></td></tr>');

//Adicionado o evento à classe no lugar do id e alterado a função .click para .on()
$(".select").on("click", function() {
    $(this).find('.cruz').toggleClass('desativado');
});
```